# Practical usage of non-data descriptors?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

I've read the docs about descriptors and I understand what they are used for, but I don't really get the usage of non-data descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

I'll begin by briefly explain what are descriptors, and then I'll highlight the three main differences with classic lookups, and finaly give some practical applications (usages) of non-data descriptors.

As you already know, if an object defines one of theses methods : `__get__()`, `__set__()` or `__delete__()`, we can consider it as a descriptor.

- If it ONLY defines the  `__get__()` method, we call it a *non-data
  descriptor*.
- If it defines `__set__()` or `__delete__()`, we call it a *data
  descriptor*.

A non-data descriptor is used when you access data (data lookup).

We will take the example provided in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html):

Create a class :

```
class A:
    x = 5

a = A()
print(a.x)
```

Here the value of `x` is obtained via a lookup in the dictionary of the object.
And in this example, the value of `x` is stored in memory.

Now, we will create a non-data descriptor called "Ten":

```
class Ten:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return 10

class A:
    x = 5
    y = Ten()

a = A()
print(a.y)
```

**First main difference**: Here, `y` is NOT  obtained via a lookup in the dictionary of the object. Instead, it calls the `__get__()` method of the descriptor "Ten", which returns the value `10`.

**Second main difference**: An other important difference is that `10` was NOT stored in memory when the object was created. When the `__get__()` method is called, the value `10` is computed dynamically. We call it a "dynamic lookup".

Now, that we understand the main basic differences between using or not using a non-data descriptor, we can go deeper.

First,
In the example above, using a descriptor is not really useful (because we could just use a data attribute or create a getter method) and in fact you should prefer the first lookup type (via the dictionary of the object) when you just want to get a constant.

**Third main difference**:
When you use a descriptor, you give the control of data access to the descriptor: the class will not control it anymore. That's a huge difference. The data access is outsourced.
You can see a descriptor as a way to manage the access to the data of an instance. When you don't use a descriptor, the manager is the class itself. When you use a descriptor, the descriptor controls what will be done when accessing the data. When you use a descriptor, you delegate this work to the descriptor. I think that this third difference is the key to understand what could be some practical applications of non-data descriptors.

This can be useful in many use cases:

For example, say you have to write 20 classes, and for these classes you will have to log the access to specific data: instead of writing lines of codes to write logs in each class, you'll just have to write a non-data descriptor and use it in all of you classes when needed.
That's very useful. You will write less lines of codes, and so you will limit the possibilties of making errors / creating bugs, and the debugging time. You will too assure a constant behavior between the classes that use the same descriptor.

There is more to know about non-data descriptor than just that of course, but I think that these points are key points to help understand what could be some of their practical applications.

That's all for the non-data descriptors.

I'll add a note on the other descriptors (data descriptors): from what I said in the last example (using logs), we begin to see one of the main application of descriptors in Python.

Like a lot of cs engineers / developers, my favourite hobby is not to spend time debugging code.

And one good practice to avoid that is to check different things in the code before bugs happens, what we call "sanity checks". For example we will want to check the arguments : check their types, avoid "Out Of Bounds errors", or ZeroDivionErrors, etc. and raise exceptions when appropriate.
For this purpose, we could use a descriptor.
Rather than writing lines and lines of codes for checking each argument of each attributes of each class, we could use data descriptors, in order to avoid unnecessary repetition.
So, say that for a project you will have a lot of attributes in a lot of classes that have to respect some constraints like: their types must be int or float, their value must be positive, but less than 1000, etc. instead of coding predicates and raise exceptions everywhere, you code all of this only one time and use it where it's needed.

This answer and your question is not about data descriptor so I stop here. One could refer to the Python's doc for more details here:https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#custom-validators . Just for information, descriptors can impact memory, storage, deletion, lookup and helps to understand how Python internally works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the log example feels like the one from the documentation. It's probably way more useful for data descriptors, so both setters and getters are logged.

Comment: Absolutely, that's the example from the docs: at the top of my answer I said  "We will take the example provided in the docs". I'm not sure what you are looking for? I didn't say that the only use of non-data descriptors  is for logging... That is just an example. A really useful usage is to manage data access. You have perhaps something specific in mind ?

Comment: I don't have anything in mind, that's why I was looking for a specific example usage for non-data descriptors. All the examples I found until now were using data descriptors, but I didn't find anything yet where I want to use a non-data descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a novel example for supporting re-initialisation of an attribute. With a hardware device that's in an unknown state, you may want long time outs on the initial contact. Once discovered, those buffers aren't to be used. Same goes if it is directly set.

```
class Creds:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        instance.creds = expensive_operation()
        return instance.creds

class Device:
    creds = Creds()

d = Device()
print(d.creds)         # invokes class attribute which sets instance attribute
print(d.creds)         # invokes instance attribute
d.creds = 'activated'  # sets instance attribute
del d.creds            # delete instance attribute
print(d.creds)         # invokes class attribute again
```